# How do I get a specific string from a text file in C++

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a text file with this input:

> Caroline went to the sea, and she forgot her boat.
>
> Patrick went to the sea, and he drowned.

How do I get the word sea and the whole line with the word sea?

So basically when I type `sea` the output needs to be:

> Caroline went to the sea, and she forgot her boat.
>
> Patrick went to the sea, and he drowned.

This is what I currently have:

```
int main () {

  // Create a text string, which is used to output the text file
  string myText;

  // Read from the text file
  ifstream MyReadFile("myfile.txt");

  while (getline (MyReadFile, myText)) {
  // Output the text from the file
    cout << myText;
  }

  // Close the file
  MyReadFile.close();
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: OT: `MyReadFile.close();` is redundant. You can omit it. The destructor will close the file for you.

Comment: The problem is I want to have an option where I can write my own string in the code and then it will output the line for me,  I have a big text file and when I write sea, I want to get the whole line and only lines with sea.

Comment: You probably should edit your question and add that comment.

Comment: Your current program makes no attempt at reading the "word" for which to filter output lines with. It seems that would be a good place to start. Further, the specific details are important as well. For example, if the file contained the line "Bob is a seaman.", does that still qualify, or would it only qualify when the token "sea" appears distinctly within the line body. The latter is considerably more complicated than you may first think, especially when it comes to handling punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you just need is to iterate the lines of your file and see if the line contains the word you want. If it does, just print the line. Here is the core of what you need:

```
while (getline (MyReadFile, myText)) {
  if(myText.find(yourString)!=std::string::npos){
           cout<<myText<<\n;
  }
}
```

The if statement checks if it the string `yourString` (which is "sea" in your example) is a substring of line. If it is, it will output the line.

Comment: Thankyouuuuuuu <3 <3

Comment: You should check it as correct answer if it worked for everyone who will look at this question.